# Class, Object, Trait, Sealed Trait in Scala

Tags: java, scala, oop, functional-programming

I am from `OOP` background and and want to clear my idea about `Object`, `Classes`, `Trait`, `Sealed Trait` and `Case Classes` in `Scala`, I am writing below what I understand about it so far:

We create `Object`, when we want to code some utility functions inside it and we can access it directly, without using "new" keyword like "Static" classes in Java.

We create `Classes`, when we are coding for verb means an object and it's behavior encapsulated same as we code for classes in Java and we instantiate it using "new" keyword.

We create `Trait` when we want to code same as Abstract classes in `Java`.

We create `Sealed Trait` when we want to achieve functionality as same Enum in Java.

We create `Case classes` when we can expect that this class can be used for pattern matching in future similar to instanceOf in Java.

Is my understanding correct about all these?

Comment: Only commenting on "Trait": as your classes can inherit more than one trait (mix-ins), I would not compare it to Java abstract classes.

Comment: You are saying, we can extend more than 1 Trait in class but Java restrict us to extend only one class at a time?. If yes, is there any other difference?

Comment: Yes, you can extend as many traits as you like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're more or less right about most of the facts you've stated if you look into them with an OOP eye. But we have more to them.

### Object

Objects in Scala can be seen from a Functional Programming perspective as *modules*. They do serve the purpose of aggregating similar kinded functions that you have called "utility functions". But they have additional meanings as well.

An `object` can be seen as a singleton object, as you can have an `object` that inherits a particular `trait` or `class`.

```
trait Bird
object Duck extends Bird
```

You also have the concept of *companion object*. That is an object that have module functions related to that class and you can even refer `private` members of the object from the class.

```
class Dog {
  def eat(food: Food) = Dog.preferredFoods.contains(food)
}

object Dog {
  private val preferredFoods = List(Ribeye, DogFood, Banana)
  def walk(dog: Dog) = ???
}
```

### Class

You are right about classes. They relate quite close to the Java concept.

### Trait

One way to view a `trait` in Scala is as an `abstract class`. But note you can also have an `abstract class` in Scala, with the same behaviour as in Java. So what's the difference?

As pointed in the comment, several `trait`s can be mixed in together.

Also `trait`s can be regarded as a Java `interface` if it's completely abstract, that is all methods are abstract as with Java. In fact, if you're targeting interop with Java, that's the way to declare an `interface`.

A `sealed trait` is just a way to tell the compiler that you won't have any classes or other traits that inherit this one except for the ones in the same file. This serves the purpose of pattern matching as you pointed out about case classes, so the compiler is able to tell if the pattern match is exhaustive with a warning. But also note the Scala has `enum`.

### Case class

Case classes can be used with a `sealed trait` for the purpose of pattern matching. But a `case class` is more like a "value class". The `case` makes the compiler generate a bunch of boilerplate code so you don't have to.

You have an automatic "companion object" so you can instantiate object without the `new`, with the auto generated `apply` function.

You have automatic `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString` and `copy` implementations. And you have automatic `val`s for all constructor's parameters.

```
scala> case class Room(area: Int)
defined class Room

scala> var r = Room(16)
r: Room = Room(16)

scala> r.hashCode
res2: Int = 1313771839

scala> r == Room(16)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> r == Room(15)
res4: Boolean = false

scala> r.toString
res5: String = Room(16)

scala> r.area
res6: Int = 16

scala> case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
defined class Point

scala> val p = Point(1, 1)
p: Point = Point(1,1)

scala> val p1 = p.copy(y = 0)
p1: Point = Point(1,0)
```